# Is there a way to read a .txt file and store each line to memory?

Tags: python, file

I am making a little program that will read and display text from a document. I have got a test file which looks like this:

```
12,12,12
12,31,12
1,5,3
...
```

and so on. Now I would like Python to read each line and store it to memory, so when you select to display the data, it will display it in the shell as such:

```
1. 12,12,12
2. 12,31,12
...
```

and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: Show us your code so far

Comment: @bjarneh readlines() is not memory efficient.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary the file is only 3 lines long :)

Comment: i am trying to show you guys my code but i don't know how to format it on this website. can anyone help me?

Comment: @VincenTTTTTTTTTTTT indent your code, i.e. let each line of your code start with 4 white spaces or one TAB.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know it is already answered :)  To summarize the above:

```
# It is a good idea to store the filename into a variable.
# The variable can later become a function argument when the
# code is converted to a function body.
filename = 'data.txt'

# Using the newer with construct to close the file automatically.
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# Or using the older approach and closing the filea explicitly.
# Here the data is re-read again, do not use both ;)
f = open(filename)
data = f.readlines()
f.close()


# The data is of the list type.  The Python list type is actually
# a dynamic array. The lines contain also the \n; hence the .rstrip()
for n, line in enumerate(data, 1):
    print '{:2}.'.format(n), line.rstrip()

print '-----------------'

# You can later iterate through the list for other purpose, for
# example to read them via the csv.reader.
import csv

reader = csv.reader(data)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

It prints on my console:

```
 1. 12,12,12
 2. 12,31,12
 3. 1,5,3
-----------------
['12', '12', '12']
['12', '31', '12']
['1', '5', '3']
```

Answer (score 5):

Try storing it in an array

```
f = open( "file.txt", "r" )
a = []
for line in f:
    a.append(line)
```

Comment: very simple way of doing it.!!

Comment: Also known as `a = open("file.txt").readlines()`, or more equivalently `a = list(open("file.txt"))`. You should really be using a `with` statement to close the file; this relies on CPython ref-counting semantics to do so and won't operate as expected under e.g. PyPy.

Comment: doesn't it run into problems if the text is very large with more number of lines in the file??

Comment: but the thing is, i have got two different options, the load option; which loads the text from the file and the Display option which will then (after you loaded it) "print" all the lines individually

Comment: just cycle through the array `a` to print out your line i.e. `a[0]` to show line 1

Comment: but wouldnt that just print the same line over and over?

Comment: @anselm only thing, i want to make it so it has a numeration in front of each line like:
       `1. 12-12/12
       2. 12-31/12`

Comment: Print out the index as well i.e. `print(input+". "+a[input])` so 1 will be `1. 12,12,12`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for @PePr excellent solution. In addition, you can try to print the .txt file with the built-in method `String.join(data)`. For example:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
print(''.join(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also be interested in the `csv` module. It lets you parse, read and write to files in the comma-separated values( csv) format...which your example appears to be in.

Example:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader( open( 'file.txt', 'rb'), delimiter=',' )
#Iterate over each row
for idx,row in enumerate(reader):
    print "%s: %s"%(idx+1,row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt') as o:
    for i,t in enumerate(o.readlines(), 1):
        print ("%s. %s"% (i, t))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

t=1

with open('sample.txt') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        num = line.strip() # contains current line
        if num:
            fn = '%d.txt' %t # gives the name to files t= 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt .....
            print('%d.txt Files splitted' %t)
            #fn = '%s.txt' %num
            with open(fn, 'w') as outf:
                outf.write('%s\n' %num) # writes current line in opened fn file
                t=t+1
```